# function to check if php is already executed for cron

Tags: php, cron

Ealier I used function in a seperate file that could be call by script for cron.

```
function processExists($file = false) {

   $exists     = false;
   $file       = $file ? $file : basename(__FILE__);

   $command = "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $file";
   exec($command, $pids);
   if (count($pids) > 1) {
      $exists = true;
   }
   return $exists;
}
```

It could be executed from any php script as:

```
if (processExists(basename(__FILE__))) {
   echo 'Process in already running ';
   exit(0);
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work in Debian6.
Now I add in the beginning of every script:

```
$fh = fopen(__FILE__, 'r');
if (!flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
   echo 'Script is already running!!!' . "\n";
   exit(0);
}
```

It causes duplication of code in every script I tried to create function in a seperate file to call from any php script when neccessary, for example something like this:

```
function stopIfRunning($file)
{
    $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
    if(!flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
        echo 'Script is already running!!!' . "\n";
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

And calling from php script:

```
stopIfRunning(__FILE__);
```

But it doesn't work in this case. Could you please explain why it doesn't work in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is with $fh on stopIfRunning function. If the file with with functiona changed it with:

```
$fh = null;
function stopIfRunning($file)
{
    global $fh;
    echo $file, "\n";
    $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
    if (!$fh) {
        echo 'Failed to open file', "\n";
    }
    if(!flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
        echo 'Script is already running!!!' . "\n";
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

And call it in the file that should be launched using cron:

```
stopIfRunning(__FILE__);
```

Here global variable is used, which is not good. It would be great if somebody suggest a solution without global variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make sure the service is running, use Daemontools or Monit.

And personally, I would use plain Bash, not PHP, if custom implementation needed.

BTW, you can easily debug your `ps` command in terminal.

Comment: Thanks, for you response. Job is done by php escipt that uses Zend_Framework, so it would be good to check it from php script, if I didn't need it, perhaps I would try to use plain bash.

Answer (score 0):

**FILE** it is name of running file.

```
stopIfRunning(__FILE__);

function stopIfRunning($file)
{
    $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
    ....
}
```

Here you tried open this executed file for lock.

Comment: Yes, that is why I call stopIfRunning(__FILE__); from php file that is launched by cron. Does it seem right? I have stopIfRunning in other file that is included in every file that is executed by cron to check, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user366534 may be problem in access right. Procces that run this procces couldn't lock it. Try chmod 0777 this_file.php

Comment: It looks like it has access right 0777. It executes script even if it's already working, it seems rather confusing.

Comment: @user366534 i'll launch it in few hours. now i can't. ok?

Comment: Ramil, did you have a chance to try it?